# Curl/php request moving to localhost after second request

Tags: php, json, curl, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to get a json result from a website to analyze in my system.

In the first request of the day I receive `Status 200 OK` I get the result that I'm expecting.

But if I try to get the result again making a refresh in the page for example, I receive the following error

> "close Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache "

With the following HTTP HEADER

```
"HTTP/1.1 302 Found : Moved Temporarily Location: http://localhost Cache-Control: private, no-cache, max-age=0, no-store, must-revalidate Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 +0000 Pragma: no-cache
```

For some reason the server returns error 302 and move to localhost and I have to wait until the next day to get the result 200 again.

Running `var_dump(curl_error($curl));`. I get  `bool(false)`

My code

```
 <?php  $cookie="files/cookies.txt";
    $url = "https://extra.bet365.com/ResultsApi/GetResults?sportName=sport&sportId=146&fixtureId=104716787&competitionId=20700663&fromDate=2021-07-01T04:05:00&toDate=2021-07-01T04:05:00&challengeId=62233643&marketOverride=";
    
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
    
    $headers = array(
       "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
       "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
       "Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
       "Connection: keep-alive",
      );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    var_dump($resp);  ?>
```

Comment: Is the file `files/cookies.txt` (or the directory `files`) writable ?

Comment: Yes, It is writable and basically has the information about the login... In the browser the cookies doesn't change when I do a request.